# What is the updated syntax to dplyr's filter_at() & vars(starts_with("foo")) in dplyr 1.0.7?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use `filter()` from `{dplyr}` using selection helpers from `{tidyselect}`. For example, I may run into a situation where I have either of the following three data frames:

```r
df_1 <-
  tribble(~identification_number, ~value,
          1, "a",
          2, "b",
          3, "c",
          4, "d",
          5, "e")

df_2 <-
  tribble(~identification_hash, ~value,
          1, "f",
          2, "g",
          3, "h",
          4, "i",
          5, "j")

df_3 <-
  tribble(~identification_WHATEVER, ~value,
          1, "t",
          2, "u",
          3, "v",
          4, "w",
          5, "x")
```

If I have the `identification` values for which I want to filter any given data:

```r
ids_to_keep <- c(2, 4, 5)
```

then the manual (yet undesired) way is to tackle each one such that:

```r
df_1 %>%
  filter(identification_number %in% ids_to_keep)

df_2 %>%
  filter(identification_hash %in% ids_to_keep)

df_3 %>%
  filter(identification_WHATEVER %in% ids_to_keep)
```

But since I can't anticipate the exact name that will appear in the data's colname, I need a robust way that says: *filter the data according to the column that starts with "identification"*.

[From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57401510/6105259) I found that the following works great:

```r
df_1 %>% # or df_2 or df_3
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("identification")), all_vars(. %in% ids_to_keep))
```

However, `filter_at()` is superseded. What is the canonical way to do the same in dplyr v 1.0.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_at`, `_if`, and `_all` functions have been retired. Instead, a new helper function called `across` has been added that works inside the standard dplyr verbs (`filter`, `mutate`, `summarize`, `select`). `across`, in turn, accepts tidyselect syntax, making it easy to select columns programmatically. The new syntax makes it easy to combine single-column operations (as in earlier versions of dplyr) with `across` operations that affect multiple columns.

Using the "mtcars" data set as an example, you can use `across` and `starts_with`. Here I'm selecting the "mpg" column using just its first two letters:

```
filter(mtcars, across(starts_with('mp'), ~ . > 30))

                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Fiat 128       32.4   4 78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4 75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4 71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Lotus Europa   30.4   4 95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
```

The filter for your data sets would look like:

```
df_1 %>% filter(across(starts_with("identification"), ~ . %in% ids_to_keep))
```