# How to combine filter(across(starts_with("foo"), ~ . logical-condition)) with mutate(bar = map2(...))?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to use `dplyr`'s `filter()` in combination with selection helpers such as `starts_with()`.

The current post is a follow-up on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771281/6105259), but in a bit more sophisticated data structure that involves *list-columns* and `map2()` from `{purrr}` package.

Consider the following `my_mtcars` data frame:

```r
library(tibble)

my_mtcars <-
  mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("cars")
```

I want to filter any column that *starts with/contains* the string `"cars"`, to keep only the following cars:

```r
cars_to_keep <- c("Merc 240D", "Fiat X1-9", "Ferrari Dino")
```

So from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771281/6105259) we learned how to use selection helpers with `filter()` such that:

```r
library(dplyr)

filter(my_mtcars, across(contains("cars"), ~ . %in% cars_to_keep))

##           cars  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
## 1    Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.0  1  0    4    2
## 2    Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.9  1  1    4    1
## 3 Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.5  0  1    5    6
```

So far so good.

The problem arises with the following data structure:

```r
higher_level_tibble <- 
  tibble(my_data         = list(my_mtcars),
         the_cars_i_want = list(cars_to_keep))

## # A tibble: 1 x 2
##   my_data        the_cars_i_want
##   <list>         <list>         
## 1 <df [32 x 12]> <chr [3]>
```

Although the following works:

```r
library(purrr)

higher_level_tibble %>%
  mutate(my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~filter(.x, cars %in% .y)))

## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##   my_data        the_cars_i_want my_filtered_data
##   <list>         <list>          <list>          
## 1 <df [32 x 12]> <chr [3]>       <df [3 x 12]>
```

This doesn't:

```r
higher_level_tibble %>%
  mutate(my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~ filter(.x, across(starts_with("cars"), ~ . %in% .y))))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `my_filtered_data`.
>
> i `my_filtered_data = map2(...)`.
>
> x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
>
> i Input `..1` is `across(starts_with("cars"), ~. %in% .y)`.
>
> x the ... list contains fewer than 2 elements

How can I utilize `tidyselect` helpers in `filter()`, all within `purrr::map2()`?

---

EDIT

---

*desired output*

```r
higher_level_tibble %>%
  mutate(my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, 
                                 .y = the_cars_i_want, 
                                 .f = ~ .x %>% filter( from the col in .x whose header starts with "cars", return only values that appear in .y )))

## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##   my_data        the_cars_i_want my_filtered_data
##   <list>         <list>          <list>          
## 1 <df [32 x 12]> <chr [3]>       <df [3 x 12]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by @Paul Smith revealed that my own code that did not work, i.e.,

```r
higher_level_tibble %>%
  mutate(my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~ filter(.x, across(starts_with("cars"), ~ . %in% .y))))
```

could be fixed with an anonymous function such as:

```r
higher_level_tibble %>%
  mutate(my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~ filter(.x, across(starts_with("cars"), function(x) x %in% .y))))

## # A tibble: 1 x 3
##   my_data        the_cars_i_want my_filtered_data
##   <list>         <list>          <list>          
## 1 <df [32 x 12]> <chr [3]>       <df [3 x 12]>
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, using `purrr::pmap_dfr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_mtcars <-
  mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("cars")

cars_to_keep <- c("Merc 240D", "Fiat X1-9", "Ferrari Dino")

higher_level_tibble <- 
  tibble(my_data         = list(my_mtcars),
         the_cars_i_want = list(cars_to_keep))

higher_level_tibble %>% 
  pmap_dfr(~ ..1 %>% filter(across(contains("cars"), \(x) x %in% ..2))) %>% 
  nest(my_filtered_data = everything()) %>% 
  bind_cols(higher_level_tibble, .)

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   my_data        the_cars_i_want my_filtered_data 
#>   <list>         <list>          <list>           
#> 1 <df [32 × 12]> <chr [3]>       <tibble [3 × 12]>
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. (1) I need a programmatic way to specify the column of interest rather than the exact colname; (2) I need the output to be as in the *desired output* (added to the bottom of the post).

Comment: Could you please clarify your comment (1), @Emman?

Comment: `my_mtcars` could arrive with a variety of colnames that start with "cars". For example: `my_mtcars_1 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_blah"); my_mtcars_2 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_bloop"); my_mtcars_3 <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("cars_pop")`. So for your code `pmap_dfr(~ ..1 %>% filter(cars %in% ..2))` to work, we need to specify *explicitly* either `filter(cars_blah %in% ..2))` or `filter(cars_bloop %in% ..2))` or `filter(cars_pop %in% ..2))`. Instead, I want a single catch-all command such as `filter(starts_with("cars") %in% ..2))`

Comment: I think my edited solution now accomplishes what you are wanting, @Emman.

Comment: Thanks, it does. It's actually funny that through your answer I found the little twist I was missing in my almost-there solution. That instead my dysfunctional `mutate(higher_level_tibble, my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~ filter(.x, across(starts_with("cars"), ~ . %in% .y))))`, I just needed to do `mutate(higher_level_tibble, my_filtered_data = map2(.x = my_data, .y = the_cars_i_want, .f = ~ filter(.x, across(starts_with("cars"), \(x) x %in% .y))))`

Comment: Glad I could have helped you, @Emman! Good luck!